# What is the origin of "s-tier" in video games?

Tags: terminology, gaming-history

It occurred to me the other day that I don't remember ever hearing the term "s-tier" (meaning *the best* in a tier list, far better than anyone else - the highest tier) before *Super Smash Bros Brawl*, when it was needed to separate Metaknight from the rest of the cast.

This may be a question for English Language stack exchange, too, but I thought I would start here. What is the earliest recorded use of the term "s-tier"?